# How to hide more than one worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Dim gender As String

gender = InputBox("What is your gender:" & vbCrLf & "(F=FEMALE,M=MALE.)")

If gender = Empty Then Exit Sub

Select Case gender

    Case "F"
        Cells(7, 12).Value = "FEMALE"
        Worksheets("M-Data Table").Visible = False
        Worksheets("MWeight - BMI").Visible = False
        Worksheets("M-Weight - Body Fat").Visible = False

    Case "M"
        Cells(7, 12).Value = "MALE"
        Worksheets("DATA").Visible = False
        Worksheets("WEIGHT & BMI").Visible = False
        Worksheets("WEIGHT $ BODYFAT").Visible = False

End Select
```

Why is there an error in the lines
Worksheets("MWeight - BMI").Visible = False

and
Worksheets("WEIGHT & BMI").Visible = False?

These are two charts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question in title and actual question are different. Anyway, answering your actual question, this happens because `Chart` sheets do not belong to `Worksheets` collection.
The remedy is to use `Sheets` rather `Worksheets` everywhere.